# How to add a gif image in the statusbar Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I'm pretty new to Qt and I was told that I can add a gif image to the status bar using the QMovie class. Can anyone tell how it can be done and is there any other way to do this too?

Comment: Qt often has multiple ways of doing a very specific thing like the one  that is being asked here. Still, the ways are usually (easily) countable by  fingers on one hand. It is very reasonable to ask how to do this in a specific way, and then ask for elaboration on if this is actually the idiomatic/smartest/only way to do it in Qt or not. Good question, not overly broad in any sense of the word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a QLabel, with a [QMovie](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.4/qmovie.html#details) in it.

```
QLabel label;
QMovie *movie = new QMovie("animations/fire.gif");

label.setMovie(movie);
movie->start();
```

You can then add the label to the using [QStatusBar::addWidget()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.4/qstatusbar.html#addWidget) like so:

```
statusBar()->addWidget(&label);
```

Comment: Thanks for reverting back. I appreciate it